# Как начать анимацию из предыдущей позиции

Tags: android, анимация, android-animation

Есть слой, который занимает весь экран. При необходимости нужно уменьшить его и переместить в левый угол.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.2"
        android:toYScale="0.2"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0%" />
</set>
```

Это проходит успешно. Затем, по стечению определённых условий, нужно из этого угла опять развернуть элемент на весь экран. Тут у меня начинаются сложности. Следующая анимация начинается с правого верхнего угла.

```
 <scale
        android:duration="1500"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fromXScale="0.2"
        android:fromYScale="0.2"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        />
```

Comment: Поставить `android:pivotX="100%"` пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо. Не правильно понял, значение параметра.

Comment: @eugeneek, было бы круто, если б вы это в ответ написали)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не вопрос)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры `android:pivotX` и `android:pivotY` это опорная точка, относительно которой происходит анимация, в процентах от ширины (высоты). Чтобы ваша вторая анимация начиналась там же, где закончилась первая, эти значения должны быть равны у обоих анимаций. Измените у второй `pivotX`:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
        ...
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0%" />
</set>
```